# Install Visual studio 2010 sp1 Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

when I want to install visual studio 2010 sp1 i get this error:

> KB2529927v2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is this you version of Windows Installer ? and what is your opration system?

Comment: I have windows installer 3.1 and windows 7 x86

Comment: Chances are, you already have .NET 4.5 installed and this update is a service pack for .NET 4.0. You probably don't need it, all of the updates are included in the latest version of the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think  Windows Update isn't as accurate as the Installer itself.
The solution is running a visual studio 2010 product repair from the Programs and features, located on windows control panel.

also at super user site also said :

https://superuser.com/questions/363254/kbxxxxx-does-not-apply-or-is-blocked-by-another-condition-on-your-computer

Comment: The point of an answer is not to demonstrate that you, too, can perform a Google search, but rather to *answer the question*. That means that at a minimum, you need to provide a summary of the information in the body of your answer. At least that way, when the links go dead, your answer will still be useful.

Comment: It's Not a very clear answer according to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I just installed the VS2010 SP1 again through the below link and it worked like a charm.

https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Service-Pack-1/3000-2070_4-75451099.html