# Installation Microsoft Visual studio 2010 sp1 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, servicepacks

I trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 only.
After finished installed, I get this error

[image]

I tried solutions in some [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907854/install-visual-studio-2010-sp1-error) which ask install Service Pack 1 ".exe", After I double click the installer, it fail to download the library.

[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks